# Using a pandas DataFrame to get the count of the 10th most frequent value

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, dataframe, series

I have a DataFrame that contains entries of place_ids such as:

```
place_id
11111
11111
22222
33333
44444
44444
...
```

I would like to get the count of the 10th most frequent value.

Here's what I've come up with:

```
print df.place_id.value_counts().nlargest(10).tail(1).values[0]
```

This seems like too much work.  Is there an easier way to get the count of the 10th most frequent place_id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from string import ascii_letters

np.random.seed([3,1415])
s = pd.Series(np.random.choice(list(ascii_letters), (10000,)))

vc = s.value_counts().sort_values()
vc.loc[[vc.index[-10]]]

j    204
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks.  That returns the 10th most frequent value ('j').  How do I get the count of that value?  (For example, 15) That's what I need.  I'm trying to use it as a threshold to exclude less frequent place_ids.

Answer (score 1):

You already have a decent solution I think. Here's an alternative that is marginally faster but for all practical purposes has the same performance:

```
In [165]: place_ids.value_counts().nlargest(10).tail(1).values[0]
Out[165]: 1057

In [166]: place_ids.value_counts().sort_values().iloc[-10]
Out[166]: 1057
```

FYI, for small lists that don't need Series objects, I like the Counter class in collections (obviously, this is a LOT slower if you need to do conversion of large objects):

```
from collections import Counter
print Counter(place_ids).most_common(10)[-1][1] # reports 1057
```